# How to write imported lists inside curly brackets to txt.file without brackets and quotations?

Tags: python

Trying to write some imported lists to a txt.file, but the list end up having brackets and quotations. What would be the correct way to do this? This is part of my code:

```
elif user_diet_yn in no_choices:
    clear()
    while True:
        single_diet = input("\nWhat diet would you like to follow?: ")
        if single_diet in aip_alt:
            clear()
            print("\nYour diet will be added to your Personal Diet Plan.")
            with open(file_name, mode="a") as f:
                f.write(f'\n\nAIP Diet:\nAllowed: {aipallowed}\n\nNot allowed: {aipnotallowed}')
            input("\nPress Enter to return to Main Menu!")
            break
        elif single_diet in paleo_alt:
            clear()
            print("\nYour diet will be added to your Personal Diet Plan.")
            with open(file_name, mode="a") as f:
                f.write(f'\n\nPaleo Diet:\nAllowed: {paleoallowed}\n\nNot allowed: {paleonotallowed}')
            input("\nPress Enter to return to Main Menu!")
            break
        elif single_diet in fodmap_alt:
            clear()
            print("\nYour diet will be added to your Personal Diet Plan.")
            with open(file_name, mode="a") as f:
                f.write(f'\n\nFodMap Diet:\nAllowed: {fodmapallowed}\n\nNot allowed: {fodmapnotallowed}')
            input("\nPress Enter to return to Main Menu!")
            break
        else:
            clear()
            print(f'\n"{single_diet}" not in data base! Check your spelling!')
```

I've tried putting * and ', ' inside the curly brackets in different ways, but I don't get it to work.

This is an example the output file:

AIP Diet:
Allowed: ['meat (preferably grass-fed)', 'fish', 'vegetables (excluding nightshade vegetables)', 'sweet potatoes', 'fruit (small quantities)', 'coconut milk', 'avocado oil', 'olive oil', 'coconut oil', 'dairy-free fermented foods (such as kombucha, sauerkraut, kefir made with coconut milk, or kimchi)', 'honey', 'maple syrup (small quantities)', 'fresh non-seed herbs (such as basil, mint, or oregano)', 'green tea (and nonseed herbal teas)', 'bone broth', 'vinegars', 'grass-fed gelatin', 'arrowroot starch']

Not allowed: ['eggs', 'goji berries', 'rosehip seeds', 'cape gooseberries', 'adzuki beans', 'alfalfa sprout seeds', 'ashwagandha', 'eggplant', 'black-eyed peas/beans', 'fenugreek seeds', 'broad beans', 'brown beans', 'bean sprouts', 'beans', 'bean pasta', 'edamame beans', 'fava beans', 'green beans', 'green peas', 'french beans', 'jalapeños', 'peanut butter', 'peanuts', 'kidney beans', 'chickpeas', 'lima beans', 'lentils', 'mung beans', 'bell pepper', 'pepino', 'pimento pepper', 'potatoes', 'quorn', 'soy', 'sugar peas', 'soy beans', 'soy cream', 'soy flour', 'soy milk', 'soy yogurt', 'black beans', 'tofu', 'tamarillo', 'tomatoes', 'tomatillos', 'wax beans', 'white beans', 'peas', 'pea shoots', 'dairy products', 'nuts', 'seeds', 'cereals', 'grains', 'rice', 'aniseed', 'bee pollen', 'cayenne pepper', 'chili', 'curry', 'dill seed', 'juniper berries', 'fennel seeds', 'green pepper', 'cardamom', 'cilantro seeds', 'allspice', 'cumin', 'licorice root', 'nutmeg', 'paprika', 'rose pepper', 'red pepper', 'celery seeds', 'caraway seeds', 'star anis', 'black pepper', 'sumac', 'white pepper', 'agave syrup', 'acrylamide', 'alkohol', 'aloe vera', 'aspartame', 'baking soda', 'chocolate', 'chlorella', 'citric acid', 'date syrup', 'grape seed oil', 'legumes', 'nightshade vegetables', 'sugar', 'alternative sugars', 'oils (other than coconut oil, olive oil, avocado oil)', 'herbs derived from seeds', 'food additives', 'processed foods', 'caffeine', 'tobacco', 'artificial sweeteners', 'NSAID (ibuprofen)']

I want it to be without brackets and quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are storing all the items in a list and you are writing the whole list in the file, but not the contents in a list one by one,

Here is an example of what you should do

```html
f.write(f'\n\nAIP Diet:\n')

f.write(f'Allowed: ')
for eatables_allowed in aipallowed:
    f.write(f'{eatables_allowed},')
  
f.write(f'\n\nNot allowed: ')
for eatables_not_allowed in aipallowed:
    f.write(f'{eatables_not_allowed},')
```

Answer (score -1):

Can You please add a sample output file in the question,It would be helpful for anyone who wants to see the problem,

Meanwhile, you can use format method : [format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

You should also check with python version : https://realpython.com/courses/python-3-f-strings-improved-string-formatting-syntax/

Comment: Updated with sample output file!